# Laravel 5.3 validation with multiple fields

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I need to do a validation in Laravel 5.3 with a Validator, but after some searches I don't found the solution and it's why I'm here.

As example, I have 3 tables:
users (can have multiple stores, can have multiple persons)
stores (can have multiple persons)
persons (can have multiple stores)
person_store

So, after users login he needs to:

1. Select a store
2. Select a person
3. Indicate person pin

At this moment the user is in a page like http://example.dev/store/1/user/2 with a form to indicate his pin.

When the users submit this form, I need validate:

- person.id = person id (value in url)
- person.user_id = user id (value in Session)
- person.pin = pin (hash of value submitted on the form page)
- person_store.store_id = store id (value in url)
- person_store.person_id = person id (value in url)

What is the best way to do it? Any example?

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'pin' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

EDIT (what I have at this moment):

```
public function login(Request $request, $storeId, $personId)
{
    $pin = $request->input('pin', '');
    $store = Store::findOrFail($storeId);
    $person = Person::findOrFail($personId);

    if (!Hash::check($pin, $person->pin)) {
        return $this->showPersonLoginForm($request, $storeId, $personId);
    } else {
        if (Hash::needsRehash($person->pin)) {
            $person->pin = Hash::make($pin);
            $person->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The validator class isn't really the right tool to use here.  I'd suggest looking into the Form Request objects, specifically the part about authorization.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#authorizing-form-requests.

Comment: The Validation class is primarily to make sure that the data you're getting from the request is present and in the format(s) that you need in order to process it. Is that what you want to do? Or do you want to verify that the user attempting the request is authorised to do so (for example, they've entered the correct pin)?

Comment: What I want to do is validate if the user entered the correct pin to after that access to another restrict page. What I have in this moment is a validation on the Controller to do that. However, after some days and review my own code I thinked that maybe I'm doing it wrong and that I should use a validator. Please check my edit to see what I have right now and if it looks fine. Thank you.